# How to revoke Google account access from within an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I have a Chrome browser extension that requests access using chrome.identity.getAuthToken, and is working as expected. In the extension you can logout using:

```
var do_logout = function() {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': false}, function(token) {
        chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token:token}, function(){
            display_login();
        });
    });
};
```

Which again is working fine. The issue is when you log back in. Ideally I want the extension to ask for permission again - mainly for testing from different accounts - but even when I request a login with interactive=true I don't get the interactive UI, like this:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true }, function(token) {
```

I can login to my [Google Accounts page](http://www.google.com/accounts/Login) and revoke access from there, but it's a bit of a faff, and it feels cleaner that if I want to signout from something that I would have to grant permission again to sign back in.

Is there a way of an extension revoking it's own access to a users account? I would presume so, but I am hitting a wall on Google. The best I found is this "[Revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)", but it feels like there should be a way to do it with [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) or [chrome.permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Answer (score 2):

As I know, the chrome identity is controlled by the Google account signed into the Chrome browser, not the web session for Google. Chrome app identities are tied to the Google account signed into Chrome. You can [change the current signed in account in Chrome settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en&ref_topic=1693469), but I recommend you [create a new Chrome profile instead](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&ref_topic=1678460).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try setting up multiple Chrome profiles.

Comment: No problem. In the meanwhile, please mark this answered if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used `chrome.identity.clearAllCachedAuthTokens()` and it works fine.

I had this problem a few weeks back when trying to use `removeCachedAuthToken()`
Because I'm using a thrid party website for authentication, apparently the removeCache doesn't work unless you are doing it all with Google. I don't remember where I read that, too much Googling...